# how to pass the value from checkboxes in single list from Urwid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, checkbox, listbox, urwid

Hi everyone I'm new with the urwid. I want to send the values of checkboxes which are selected from checkbox list it will add into the list and send this list  to  the next page. Here below is my code in that i am getting empty value while printing the List box value.

```
    from urwid import (CheckBox, SimpleListWalker, ListBox, Text, Frame,
                   MainLoop, ExitMainLoop, connect_signal)

words = ["obelus", "bumfuzzle", "rubaboo", "ballyhoo", "everywhen",
         "octothorpe", "meldrop", "sozzled", "pizazz", "pronk"]
palette = [
        ('reverse','light gray','black'),
        ('important','dark blue','light gray',('standout','underline')),
        ('buttn','white','default'),
        ('buttnf','white','dark blue','bold'),
        ('h2', 'white,underline,bold', 'dark red'),
        ('header','white','dark red', 'bold'),
        ('body', 'default', 'default'),]

def update_footer(widget, state):

  footer.set_text(", ".join([checkbox.label
                            for checkbox in checkboxes
                            if checkbox.state is True]))

checkboxes = []

for word in words:
  checkbox = CheckBox(label=word)
  connect_signal(checkbox, "postchange", update_footer)
  checkboxes.append(checkbox)

list_walker = SimpleListWalker(contents=checkboxes)

listbox = ListBox(list_walker)

footer = Text(markup="")


print(listbox)
frame = Frame(header=header , body=listbox)

MainLoop(widget=frame).run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we are getting the solution of above question

```
 from urwid import (CheckBox, SimpleListWalker, ListBox, Text, Frame,
                   MainLoop, ExitMainLoop, connect_signal)

import urwid

choices = ["obelus", "bumfuzzle", "rubaboo", "ballyhoo", "everywhen",
         "octothorpe", "meldrop", "sozzled", "pizazz", "pronk"]



def item_chosen(widget,state):
    list1 = [checkbox.label
                            for checkbox in checkboxes
                            if checkbox.state is True]

def exit_program(button):
    list1 = [checkbox.label
                            for checkbox in checkboxes
                            if checkbox.state is True]



    txt = urwid.Text(u"Selected Items are "+str(list1))
    fill = urwid.Filler(txt, 'top')

    frame2 = Frame(body=fill)

    MainLoop(widget=frame2).run()

    #raise ExitMainLoop()


checkboxes = []

for c in choices:
    checkbox = CheckBox(label=c)
    connect_signal(checkbox, "postchange",item_chosen)
    checkboxes.append(checkbox)



main = urwid.Padding(ListBox(SimpleListWalker(checkboxes)), left=2, right=2)

top = urwid.Overlay(main, urwid.SolidFill(u'\N{MEDIUM SHADE}'),
    align='center', width=('relative', 60),
    valign='middle', height=('relative', 60),
    min_width=20, min_height=9)


footer = urwid.Button(u'submit')
urwid.connect_signal(footer, 'click', exit_program)


frame = Frame(body=top,footer = footer)


urwid.MainLoop(widget=frame, palette=[('reversed', 'standout', '')]).run()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).